# Why does my generated function not find the variable in my function generator?

Tags: r

```
theta = 6
C_gumbel_u12 <- expression(exp(-((-log(u1))^theta +(-log(u))^theta)^(1/theta)))
C12_u1_u <- function(u){
  force(u)
  deriv(C_gumbel_u12,"u1",func = TRUE)
}
x <- 0.54
C12_u1 <- C12_u1_u(u = x)
pryr::unenclose(C12_u1)
```

As show above，I want to write a function generator using the `deriv` function. But I get the following error:

```
C12_u1(0.45)
# Error in C12_u1(0.45) : object 'u' not found
```

Comment: I’ve changed the terminology, since in R “factory functions” are known as “function generators”, and the term “factory function” isn’t widely known.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that *`deriv`*, not `C12_u1_u`, generates the closure. And thus `u` is not captured in the scope of the returned function.

The best way around this is to `substitute` `u` inside the expression before passing it to `deriv`:

```
C12_u1_u <- function(u){
  expr <- eval(bquote(substitute(.(C_gumbel_u12[[1L]]), list(u = u))))
  deriv(expr, "u1", function.arg = TRUE)
}
```

Unfortunately this is quite complicated, since `substitute` expects an *unquoted* expression as its first argument, but the expression `C_gumbel_u12` is *quoted*, and wrapped inside `expression`. As a consequence, simply calling `substitute(C_gumbel_u12, list(u = u))` fails.

Instead, we need to construct our own unevaluated `substitute` call from the actual, evaluated argument, and evaluate that call. An alternative way of writing that first line without `bquote` is using the `call` function to construct the call:

```
expr <- eval(call('substitute', C_gumbel_u12[[1L]], list(u = u)))
```